# Why is my view not updating when adding data from my service to my viewmodel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I just created a new project and I am trying to add some data to the collection in my ViewModel, however when I add data to it, it does add but it wont update the UI.

This is where I set the DataContext and where I am trying to add some content to the collection

```
ProxyService ps;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new BaseViewModel();

    ps = new ProxyService();
    ps.AcceptConnection();
}
```

Keep in mind, it does add it to the collection there are no errors I've debugged it and it's infact in the collection.
ProxyServer.cs

```
public class ProxyService : MessageViewModel
{
    public void AcceptConnection()
    {
        Messages.Add(new MessageModel { Message = "Awaiting connection..." });
```

Here is the BaseViewModel

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public MessageViewModel MessageViewModel { get; set; } = new MessageViewModel();
}
```

And the MessageViewModel of course

```
public class MessageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<MessageModel> _messages;

    public ObservableCollection<MessageModel> Messages
    {
        get { return _messages; }
        set
        {
            _messages = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public MessageViewModel()
    {
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageModel>();
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML for the ScrolLViewer to which I am adding the data

```
<ScrollViewer  Height="380"
                           Margin="10"
                           >
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MessageViewModel.Messages}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontFamily="Consolas" 
                                           Foreground="#61d73d"
                                           Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>

</ScrollViewer>
```

The issue I am facing is that it's not updating the UI when it adds something
However! If I add something in the constructor it works just fine. As an example this works just fine, it shows it in the view accoringly

```
public MessageViewModel()
{
    Messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageModel>();
    Messages.Add(new MessageModel { Message = "Hello World!" });
}
```

My best guess is that it's adding to another instance of some sort but I am not sure, I really don't want to have to use singleton because I feel like that will ruin the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Why would adding objects to the ProxyService affect the BaseViewModel? These are two sepatare objects.

Comment: There are *obviously* two different MessageViewModel instances. One is the value of the MessageViewModel property of BaseViewModel. The other is the ProxyService instance. This will of course not work.

Answer (score 1):

`BaseViewModel` is one class and `ProxyService` another one. You can't expect `MessageModel` objects that you add to the latter affect the former and vice versa. Try to set the `DataContext` to a `BaseViewModel`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ps = new ProxyService();
    ps.AcceptConnection();
    DataContext = new BaseViewModel { MessageViewModel = ps };
}
```

Comment: Lets say I had more classes like `ProxyService` and essentially wanted to do the same thing, let's say I have another class called BookServices and I had a collection of books in the MessageViewModel, how would I then call a method like I did in the example and set it to the MessageViewModel when it's already set, I hope I madr sense

Comment: @MarkDenom: Add another property to the BaseViewModel or return objects from the services and add them to a single collection in the view model.

Comment: Could you show a small example? By all means if you don't have the time I understand, I just find it easier to read code than trying to make it up in my head.

Comment: @MarkDenom: Please ask another question if you have another issue. Your original question was not about any BookService.

Comment: Will do! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Three points of note.

1. You're setting the Window's DataContext to one instance of BaseViewModel, and then creating a separate instance of the ProxyServiceClass.
2. Your binding for the `ItemsControl`.`ItemsSource` should just be binding to a property of the DataContext, in this case Messages.
3. Don't keep recreating the ObservableCollection - just create it once and add / remove items as required. Any bound control will detect that it implements INotifyCollectionChanged and refresh itself automatically when the collection is updated.